# Virtualbox virtual machine to VMWare virtual machine

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, vmware-workstation, vmdk

I have a virtual machine in **Virtualbox 4.2.4** that runs Ubuntu 12.04 on a 20Gb `.vmdk` harddrive.

I've done a whole load of installing programs, updates, configuring, ... on the virtual machine and now I would just like to take an 'image' of the virtual machine and all the installed programs, files,... and load it into **VMWare Workstation 9**. (so I don't have to re-configure, re-install,... everything)

First of all: is this possible?
And secondly: how would I go about doing this?

Comment: You do understand that `.vmdk` more or less stands for `VMWare Disk` right?  in other words you should be able to load the file in VMWare already.

Comment: basically yes. You can try to convert to a raw image or some other standard formats (like VHD). Look into the documentation of VirtualBox it has very nice command line tools. P.S: BTW VMDK is already a VMWare disk

Comment: @Ramhound I hadn't the slightest idea, and this makes my whole question rather trivial :) If you post your comment as an answer, I'll happily mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, this should 'just work' since the VM is already in the right format. It might be a good idea to remove the Virtualbox guest additions before you move it to VMWare, but probably you can also do this after the move.

If you need to convert the image file in some way, then check out the [Virtualbox documentation](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#ovf). I've found the VBoxManage command line tool to be really powerful in the past.